# AutoHotkey activate vb.net ContextMenu

Tags: autohotkey, vb.net

I use a lot of little vb.net programs (made with VBExpress 2010) and a lot of little AutoHotkey scripts, and I really want them to be able to communicate easily.

My prime example is a `Me.Hide` form with a `NotifyIcon` that has a `ContextMenu`. The menu activates when I right-click the icon. I want a way for my AHK script to tell the .net app to open this `ContextMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^a::SendInput {AppsKey}  ; Ctrl+A to activate the right-click menu
```

If you need to select a certain item on the menu you can send arrow keys and enter usually, or the shortcut key for the item

```
^a::                     ; Ctrl+A
    SendInput {AppsKey}  ; Activate the right-click menu
    SendInput {Down 2}   ; Go down to the second item
    SendInput {Enter}
return
```

Comment: Okay, to clarify, the `Notifyicon` is visible in the tray, but I want it to be a global hotkey, so how to I bring the  `NotifyIcon` into focus? (Also sorry, I wrote this post on three hours of sleep, so a lot of details got left out)

Comment: I can only comment on the AutoHotkey side of things, in which case you can either have AutoHotkey click on the icon itself by finding the icon in the tray and clicking there, or you can have it send a shortcut key (but in that case you need to have the vb.net able to detect the shortcut key and respond to it, which I don't know how to do).  A third option might be to click the icon programmatically (i.e., send a click to the running program instead of trying to mouseClick X, Y), but that would probably be even more difficult to figure out.